# How do I auto generate/update a json file of a github repository files during commit merge using github actions? (if this is possible)

Tags: json, github-actions

Instead of using github API I want to make an auto generated/updated json file of this:

```json
github repo api link
{
  "sha": "asdfadsfasdfadf",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/git/trees/asdfasdfadsf",
  "tree": [
    {
      "path": ".gitattributes",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "asdfasdfasdfadf",
      "size": 2518,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/git/blobs/asdfasdfadsf"
    },
...
```

with the use of github actions if possible and generates a json output file like this in the repo:

```json
files.json
{
   "timestamp_created": "01-23-2023 12:34:35",
   "timestamp_updated": "01-23-2023 13:53:23", // if someone made a merge
   "files": [                                  // selected dir from github repo
       {
           "path": "Files/Sample.cs"
           "name": "Sample Script"
       },
   ]
}
...
```

I have no choice because the github api limit reach was a decent issue of my application that's why this idea might work to use an auto generated json file from repo that contents all the files of a specific directory in the repository.

Comment: What did you try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved the problem by executing a C# Console Project inside of my repository through dotnet run command since I've noticed that actions can execute commands so I tried to use dotnet and it works.

```yaml
name: Run JSON generator with C# File

on:
  push:
    branches:
        - main
  pull_request:
    types:
        - closed

jobs:
  run-csharp-file:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}

    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
      with:
        dotnet-version: '6.0.x'

    - name: Run C# file
      run: dotnet run Program.cs --project JSONGenerator/JSONGenerator.csproj > gen.json

    - name: Upload artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: gen.json
        path: gen.json
```

In my C# code, after adding objects I printed it out as json string, and then this will out as json file base on the command `> gen.json`

```cs
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this action to list all the files changed in a PR in json format.

```
- uses: jitterbit/get-changed-files@v1
  with:
    # Format of the steps output context.
    # Can be 'space-delimited', 'csv', or 'json'.
    # Default: 'space-delimited'
    format: ''
```

Source: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-all-changed-files#get-all-removed-files-as-json

Comment: I cannot use this since there is no attribute for `size` of the file. Because I have a requirement to include the `size` attribute. Thanks btw, I already solved the problem.